# Tools to convert Wind Speed and Direction to U and V to create the OBS_DOMAIN (WRF)

Tags: python-3.x, ncl

I am trying to implement the observation data to WRF model simulation as instructed in ObsNudgingGuide.pdf file

http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/docs/ObsNudgingGuide.pdf

I have the Wind turbine SCADA data contains wind speed and direction details (Table-1), I want to convert the wind speed and direction data to U and V component and use it in OBS_DOMAIN.

I am searching for the python/NCL script which could convert the SCADA Wind Speed and Wind direction to U and V or directly convert data to OBS_DOMAIN format as instructed in PDF (Image-1), It would be much help full.

[image: DateTime, Wind Speed, Wind Direction]

Table-1

```
11-09-2023 00:10    9.948   273
11-09-2023 00:20    9.972   278.4
11-09-2023 00:30    10.391  297.3
11-09-2023 00:40    10.496  283.7
11-09-2023 00:50    10.402  271.4
11-09-2023 01:00    10.570  278.9
11-09-2023 01:10    11.150  296.7
11-09-2023 01:20    9.839   313
```

Image-1 (OBS_DOMAIN format as explained in PDF)

[image: OBS_DOMAIN]